# NPM install : Git URL dependency error in package.json

Tags: git, node.js, npm

I want to set a dependency that is a Git URL of a private package in package.json I write :

```
"dependencies" : { 
    "mymodule" : "git://git@git.myrepo.com:/myproject#mybranch"
}
```

When running `npm install` I get this error :

```
git clone git://git@git.myrepo.com:/myproject.git Cloning into bare repository '/hom
/Ostro/.npm/_git-remotes/git-git-myrepo-com-myproject-git-4d838f3d'...
npm ERR! git clone git://git.myrepo.com:/myproject.git
npm ERR! git clone git://git.myrepo.com:/myproject.git fatal: Unable to look up
git.myrepo.com (port ) (Servname() not supported for ai_socktype)
npm ERR! Error: git "clone" "--mirror" "git://git.myrepo.com:/myproject.git" "/hom
/Ostro/.npm/_git-remotes/git-git-myrepo-com-myproject-git-4d838f3d" failed with 128
npm ERR! at ChildProcess. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:56:20)
npm ERR! at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:99:17)
npm ERR! at maybeClose (child_process.js:638:16)
npm ERR! at Socket.ChildProcess.spawn.stdin (child_process.js:815:11)
npm ERR! at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
npm ERR! at Socket._destroy.destroyed (net.js:358:10)
npm ERR! at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
```

But it looks like npm call `git clone --mirror git://git.myrepo.com ...etc`
does it not suppose to call `git clone --mirror git.myrepo.com ...etc` instead ?

Do someone already face that ? or have any clue ?

Comment: Git URL in your `package.json` is antipattern!

Comment: Calling things an "antipattern" without any explanation is an antipattern

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The valid forms are below.  If you are using username@, you need to specify either ssh or https. Also, I am not sure the :/ is valid if you are not using an account.

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname:project.git#commit-ish
git+ssh://user@hostname/project.git#commit-ish
git+http://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
git+https://user@hostname/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

Comment: If you use a private REPO, just connect it following the same pattern: for instance, I forked an NPM module and pushed to a private Atlessian Stash server in a private git repo... My dependency was the following: "crafity": "git+https://repos.xxx.com/scm/project-a/isp-npm-module-loggin.git#HEAD"

Comment: Note that git URLs in package.json might break in Cygwin: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7357